# How to return 403 status code instead of 302 when access it denied?

Tags: sitecore-client, seo

I have Sitecore 8.2 with SXA, I need to change page status code in case user is not login, but try to open some pages only for login users.
 Basically Sitecore works ok, I could be redirected to login page depending on settings and etc. 
but the question is next why Sitecore return 302 status code ? How to change it to 403 at most proper way?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore does not set error status codes properly. The code handling no access redirect is done on the method `RedirectOnNoAccess` of the processor `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel`.

SXA sets the header for `NotFound` and `InternalServerError`, but not for `Forbidden`. This is done via processor `Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HtpRequestProcessed.SetStatusCode`. Use a decompiler to see the code.

You could override `RedirectOnNoAccess` to set `Context.Items["httpStatus"]` to `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden` and then override the `Process` method on `SetStatusCode` so the switch included a check for `HttpStatusCode.Forbidden` and sets the StatusCode to 403.

Comment: Thanks @josedbaez in general this is good solution. But now browser return object move here message instead of sitecore page. Do you know what to do ? Redirect at web config not help

Comment: Can you check browser console and see the URL? Is it correct?

Comment: yes I see only requested page with status 403

Comment: Problem might be that IIS is not letting the request through :S. You might need to play around with other Response settings. Try adding Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; or adding a substatuscode

Comment: @josedbaex hard to do it :) not works for me in any way but any way thanks for help